# root element does not change its display to inline

Tags: html, css

when I try to change the display property of the root html element to inline or initial, it is still of type block. Why does that happen? [image]

Comment: You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that everyone can understand it properly. [see why you shouldn't post image as a code or an error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=You%20should%20not%20post%20code,order%20to%20reproduce%20the%20problem.)

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? I can't see this as beneficial in any way

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you'd like to achieve - I can't get my head around what the html element being an inline-block would actually mean.

Comment: after you enter your description take two line spaces and paste your code and the select your code in dialog box and press ctrl + k. That will indent your code. study the article on how ask a good question on stack overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mess with the Root element (the `html` one). It's not meant to be styled or changed.

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo):

> 4. Otherwise, if the element is the root element, 'display' is set according to the table below,

And in the table you can see that `inline` (the specified value) is transformed to `block` (the computed value)

---

`display` is not the only property having a particular behavior when it comes to the root element so don't try to style it of your will have a lot of headaches.